# Proving the upper bound of the ratio of product of odd n numbers to even n numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

So question demands a proof that:

Let $$x_n = \frac 12 * \frac34 * \frac56 *  ...  * \frac{2n-1}{2n} $$

Then show that;

$$x_n \leq \frac 1{\sqrt{3n +1}} $$

So essentially what I have tried to do is use the formulas for the product of first N odd numbers and product of first N even numbers. This gives me that

$$x_n =  \frac{^{2n} C_n}{2^{2n}} $$

I have no clue if I have taken the right road. Can any one help me out with this proof ?  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: No I have not. I frankly do not know how to use induction for good proof building. Like the condition that required for using induction, what constitutes as proof in this method, etc.

Comment: There is plenty of literature available on induction. Or have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Example). If you prefer to avoid induction, please clarify which methouds you *would* like to use.

Comment: @Servaes induction looks like will be troublesome with that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ in the denominator...

Comment: This inequality can be solved by induction

Comment: @gt6989b That is easily solved by squaring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a sketch of a proof by induction; the base case is easy checked as for $n=1$ you have
$$x_1=\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3\cdot1+1}}.$$
Then the induction step; suppose $x_n\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ for some $n\geq1$. We want to show that this implies
$$x_{n+1}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}.$$
By definition of $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$, and by the induction hypothesis, we have
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}x_n\leq\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}},$$
so now it suffices to show that
$$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}.$$
Clearing denominators and squaring (where we use that all terms are positive) shows that this is equivalent to
$$(2n+1)^2(3n+4)\leq(2n+2)^2(3n+1),$$
and expanding both sides yields the obviously true statement
$$12n^3+28n^2+19n+4\leq12n^3+28n^2+20n+4.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. This resolves my doubt. Also serves as an alarm for me to learn induction based proofs.